# Adding (text) column to raster table that has no attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table

I have posted this question previously but I am going to try to rephrase it.

I have raster map, this raster map does not have the option to look at the attribute table (I know rasters do not have a ''real'' attribute table. But what I would like to do is to add a column besides the VALUE in which I can add the name (in text) that corresponds with the raster VALUE. I know for instance that landcover maps have the different landcovers stored as text in the raster file.

[image]

Comment: That's not how rasters work

Comment: @IanTurton what I mean can be seen in the example in this link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5buK.png

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has a relatively new plugin named *RasterAttributeTable* that appears to do exactly what you want.  A description and "how-to" video can be found at https://github.com/noaa-ocs-hydrography/qgis-raster-attribute-table-plugin#readme

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have indeed found this plugin already but it did not do the trick, since it does not really add the data to the raster. When I click on a region of the map with the identify features tool it still only shows the pixel value and I would like to also see additional values (in text format) like you see in land classification maps for instance.